# Expectation of random variable with omitted variable bias

Tags: statistics, random-variables, regression, expected-value, linear-regression

I am given:

$y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1range_i + \beta_2dist_i + \epsilon_i$

$E[\epsilon_i | range_i, dist_i]=0$

Then in the case where $dist_i$ is omitted:

$y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1range_i + \eta_i$

**Do we know that $E[\eta_i|range_i] =0$?**

My first instinct was to try to compute $E[\beta_2dist_i + \epsilon_i|range_i]$, but I don't know if this helps me with anything.

How can I answer my question?

Comment: You seem to be defining $\beta_0, \beta_1, \beta_2$ as real numbers and $range_i$, $dist_i$, $chem_i$, $\epsilon_i$ as random variables (likely the $i$ subscripts can be removed for simplicity). Then you seem to be defining $\eta_i = \beta_2 dist_i + \epsilon_i$.  Then you are asking if the conditional expectation of $\eta_i$, given $range_i$, is always 0.  This cannot be answered without further information on how $dist_i$ relates to $range_i$ (as well as how $\epsilon_i$ relates to $range_i$).

Comment: @Michael My apologies, I was not supposed to define $chem_i$. I have updated the question.

Comment: Without $chem_i$, you can use iterated expectations on $E[\epsilon_i | range_i, dist_i]=0$ to conclude $E[\epsilon_i | range_i] =0$. But you are not told anything about how $dist_i$ relates to $range_i$ and so you cannot compute $E[dist_i|range_i]$ from the given info.

Comment: @Michael Thank you. Therefore, we do *not* know that $E[eta_i|range_i] = 0$, correct? Also, how can I use the law of iterated expectations in the way that you described it?

Comment: You know that $$E[\eta_i|range_i] = E[\beta_2dist_i + \epsilon_i|range_i] = E[\beta_2dist_i|range_i]$$ Iterated expectations is $E[X] = E[E[X|Y]]$ for general random variables $X,Y$. For everything conditioned on $Z$ we get $E[X|Z] = E[E[X|Y,Z]]$, so if $E[X|Y,Z]=0$ for all $Y,Z$ then $E[X|Z]=0$ for all $Z$.